# PhpDoc generating warning

Tags: warnings, message, phpdoc

The warning messages generated in the document following is the message seen in all methods inside the document.

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\php72\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php on line 1198 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\php72\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php on line 1198 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Vzi.png)

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: it is a phpdoc pear package. as it shows the core.php as a line causing this warning. i will post the file here. I cant post full code here . find the code causing issue.

  
    function twig_length_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $thing)
    {
        return is_scalar($thing) ? mb_strlen($thing, $env->getCharset()) : count($thing);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution.

see link
https://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=52691

changed the function in core.php file

```
    /**
 * Returns the length of a variable.
 *
 * @param Twig_Environment $env
 * @param mixed            $thing A variable
 *
 * @return int The length of the value
 */
function twig_length_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $thing)
{
    if (is_scalar($thing)) {
        return mb_strlen($thing, $env->getCharset());
    }

    if (is_object($thing) && method_exists($thing, '__toString') && !$thing instanceof \Countable) {
        return mb_strlen((string) $thing, $env->getCharset());
    }

    return count($thing);
}
```

to following

```
/**
 * Returns the length of a variable.
 *
 * @param Twig_Environment $env
 * @param mixed            $thing A variable
 *
 * @return int The length of the value
 */
function twig_length_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $thing)
{
    if (null === $thing) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (is_scalar($thing)) {
        return mb_strlen($thing, $env->getCharset());
    }
    if (is_object($thing) && method_exists($thing, '__toString') && !$thing instanceof \Countable) {
        return mb_strlen((string) $thing, $env->getCharset());
    }
    if ($thing instanceof \Countable || is_array($thing)) {
        return count($thing);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a lot to correct this same error, so I wish to share here the complete solution : what to change and how to edit the phar file :

Copy this script in a file in your phar folder and run it with the php command line with option specified in code :

```
<?php
//to be run with php -d phar.readonly=Off -f thisFileName 
if (ini_get('phar.readonly')==1){
    die("\n\nThis script must be run with option -d phar.readonly=Off so that it can write the .phar file\n\n"); 
}

//the file you want to change
$file = 'vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php';

//the function in the file you want to change
$oldFunction = '#function twig_length_filter[^{]*[^}]*}#'; //assuming it's still the actual one line function, regex might need updates in the furure

//the replacement function
$newFunction = <<<'funct'
function twig_length_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $thing)
    {
        if (null === $thing) {
        return 0;
        }
        if (is_scalar($thing)) {
            return mb_strlen($thing, $env->getCharset());
        }
        if (is_object($thing) && method_exists($thing, '__toString') && !$thing instanceof \Countable) {
            return mb_strlen((string) $thing, $env->getCharset());
        }
        if ($thing instanceof \Countable || is_array($thing)) {
            return count($thing);
        }
        return 1;
    }
funct;

//access the phar
$p = new Phar('phpDocumentor.phar', FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME);
//extract the file
$p->extractTo('./', $file, true);

//return here if you want to check the file first
//return;

//change the function 
file_put_contents($file,
    $newFile = preg_replace(
            $oldFunction, 
            $newFunction, 
            file_get_contents($file)
        )
    );

//update the file
$p[$file] = $file;

//done
echo 'Done. Don\'t forget to delete the "vendor" folder extracted from the phar !';
```